# Null pointer exception: HTTP response code 500

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

Trying to run a web application programmatically. Wrote a code that will automatically deploy the web application. After the web application has been deployed, I call the servlet with some input using `URL` class and print the response as shown below.

```
    //code to start Tomcat server and deploy the web app
    String myUrl = "http://localhost:8080/CrossSiteScripting?user=shri&passwd=firstPassword";
    URL url = new URL(myUrl); 
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    String httpMethod = con.getRequestMethod();
    while((inputLine=in.readLine()) != null){
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println("\n----------------------\nHTTP Method : "+ httpMethod +"\nOutput: "+response.toString());
```

I am calling `doGet()` method of a servlet. Code inside the `doGet` method is shown below.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String user = request.getParameter("user");
      String pwd = request.getParameter("passwd");
      request.setAttribute("user", user);
      request.setAttribute("passwd", pwd);
      PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
      pw.write("Inside doGet method of Servlet\nuser name: "+user+"password= "+pwd);
      RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("homePage.jsp");
      view.forward(request, response);
}
```

If I comment out the last line in `doget` method which is `view.forward(request, response);`, then I am able to get expected response. But if it is not commented then I am getting `NullPointerException` and the server is returning HTTP response code `500`. 
This is the error I got while running the application using URL class.

```
    asAug 07, 2015 11:53:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
    WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
    C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\workspace\Initiate Tomcat\.
    Host: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]

    starting server...
    Aug 07, 2015 11:53:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

    Aug 07, 2015 11:53:47 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector

    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read

    Aug 07, 2015 11:53:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

    INFO: Starting service Tomcat

    Aug 07, 2015 11:53:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23

    Aug 07, 2015 11:53:48 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [173] milliseconds.
    Aug 07, 2015 11:53:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

    started.
    Initiating URL: http://localhost:8080/CrossSiteScripting?user=shri&user=manoj&user=shrikant&passwd=firstPassword&passwd=admino
    Aug 07, 2015 11:53:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CrossSiteScripting] in context with path [/] threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at penetration.testing.CrossSiteScripting.doGet(CrossSiteScripting.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:857)

    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/CrossSiteScripting?user=shri&user=manoj&user=shrikant&passwd=firstPassword&passwd=admino
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1638)
at main.java.launch.Main.main(Main.java:92)
```

The last line may be throwing exception because of `view.forward()` method. Which is forwarding the control to a `JSP.` Is there any other way to do it? I want that JSP page to be executed as it would have when opened inside a browser.

This is the directory structure:

```
    +InitiateTomcat
    |-- +src
    |---|- +main.java.launch
    |---|--- main.java //the main class from where I start Tomcat server and deploy a web application
    |---|- +penetration.testing
    |---|--- CrossSitrScripting.java // the servlet which am calling
    |-- +WebContent
          +WEB-INF
             homePage.jsp  // the homepage
```

Comment: @Javy @Garry : I tried changing it to `/homepage.jsp` but it is not working. Getting same error.

Comment: @Javy the error is because of last line `view.forward.` because I tried running it without that line and it executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

500 http status code means that the server failed to satisfy the request and that an "unexpected" error happened, I guess that the page "homePage.jsp" is not accessible through this URL, try accessing it via the browser directly to verify.

Comment: I can access it using browser

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null pointer at `CrossSiteScripting.java:41`

Which you said is:

```
view.forward(request, response);
```

So the view generated by this is null because it is unable to find homePage.jsp

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("homePage.jsp");
```

If your `homePage.jsp` in same relative location as of current page then you need to use "`homePage.jsp`" and if the `homePage.jsp` is in the root then you should use the forward slash "`/`" to point to root thus "`/homePage.jsp`"

I assume you should use forward slash in front of your jsp call while forwarding as below:

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/homePage.jsp");
```

Comment: I also think it is not able to find `homePage.jsp.` I tried changing it to `/homePage.jsp`, but still its not working. I also tried changing it to `/InitiateTomcat/homePage.jsp` where `InitiateTomcat` is the name (root) of my project. 
I will add the directory structure of the project. That may help you understand well.

Comment: @Manoj.. yes, that will help

Comment: I have added the directory structure

Comment: @Manoj .. can you try `request.getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/homePage.jsp"`

Comment: @Manoj ... As per the comment to another answer, you said that you are able to access the homePage.jsp using browser. Can you add the URL for that?

Comment: What I did was created another webapp and checked if the code is working properly or not. Then I added that servlet (`CrossSiteScripting.java`) and `homePage.jsp` to the webapp that starts TC server and deploys a servlet. Then I wrote a code that deploys the `CrossSiteScripting.java` servlet and called it. 
Anyways adding the URL: 
`http://localhost:8080/PenTesting/` this opens the index.jsp page where I manually enter the input values and after posting it, it takes me to `homePage.jsp` with the URL: `http://localhost:8080/PenTesting/CrossSiteScripting?user=admin&passwd=admin`

Comment: @Manoj .. you said you are running the server programmatically, are you sure homePage.jsp do exist in your auto deployed application?

Comment: yes, it does exists in my auto deployed application. I just created another webapp to test if it is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85405/discussion-between-manoj-and-garry).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error or exception is here

```
 RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("homePage.jsp");
```

Accessing page like `homePage.jsp` should be either an empty string or start with a '/' , if you write `homePage.jsp` directly,  the path is :

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\workspace\Initiate Tomcat\homePage.jsp
```

so you should do as follows

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/homePage.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Any content inside WEB-INF directory can not be accessed directly via URL.
Kindly  move homePage.jsp file outside WEB-INF directory and then try to access  it. I hope it will work.

regards
Sandeep